# Does the novel "Tarkin" include an obscure reference to Peter Cushing's wardrobe problem from Episode IV?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, costume, clothing

In the book [*Star Wars:  Tarkin* by James Luceno](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KAFX85Y), we find this passage (emphasis mine):

> THE DOOR TO TARKIN’S QUARTERS whooshed open, disappearing into the partition, and out he marched, dressed in worn trousers and **ill-fitting boots**, with a lightweight gray-green duster draped over his shoulders.

This amused me, because when Peter Cushing was filming his role as Grand Moff Tarkin in *Star Wars - Episode IV:  A New Hope*, his costume boots were too small.  He reached an agreement with George Lucas that he should be filmed almost exclusively from the waist up so he could wear his carpet slippers on set rather than the painfully tight boots.

[image]   [image]
*Behind the scenes photos from the set of* A New Hope, *showing Cushing in his slippers*

[image]
*Quote from Peter Cushing<sup>1</sup>, describing the problem with his boots in* A New Hope; *taken from [a fansite devoted to the actor](http://petercushingblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/star-wars-peter-cushing-and-grand-moff.html)*.

[image]
*From the site "[The Cushing Collection](http://thecushingcollection.tumblr.com/post/119882584785/peter-cushings-carpet-slippers-on-display-in-the)", this picture is captioned:  "Peter Cushing’s carpet slippers on display in the Whitstable Museum in 2013. When Cushing played Grand Moff Tarkin in STAR WARS, the boots they got for him were far too small, and so he asked George Lucas to just film the upper half of his body most of the time, while he was shuffling around in his slippers. He joked afterwards that there’s no wonder that Tarkin is such a nasty fellow - “his boots are killing him!”"*

I suspect<sup>2</sup> that this is more than mere coincidence, but I'd like some confirmation one way or the other.

### Is the novel *Tarkin*'s mention of "ill-fitting boots" an obscure reference to Cushing's problems with the boots he was supposed to wear in his role as Grand Moff Tarkin in *A New Hope*?

---

<sup>1</sup> *The quote is apparently taken from his memoir,* ['Past Forgetting’: Memoirs of the Hammer Years](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0297792830), *by Peter Cushing.*

<sup>2</sup>*I'm not the only person who made this connection:*

> Tarkin: It's James Luceno writing a book about Tarkin like Darth Plagueis.... Again, lots of small EU references that made me happy. **And I actually laughed out loud at a line that described Tarkin's boots as being "ill-fitting", because it's so meta. (The boots that were part of Tarkin's costume in ANH were too small for Peter Cushing, so he actually filmed the entire movie in bedroom slippers. There aren't any shots of Tarkin's feet in the movie. :D)**
>   -  [Source](http://www.freeworldstidesofwar.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=2444)

Comment: @DVK - it is a good start, but not an answer in itself.  You can use the Cushing-related parts of [this](http://www.scifinow.co.uk/news/star-wars-7-exclusive-james-luceno-on-tarkin-eu-canon/) interview to flesh it out, but it still wouldn't quite answer the question - I don't know what would, except an answer from Luceno himself.

Comment: heh great minds think alike. I had that interview as the next tab open for researching this. Added but still deleted.

Comment: Voted to undelete

Comment: What I want to know is, did Wayne Pygram wear slippers when he briefly played the role in Episode III!

Answer (score 5):

- *"Tarkin"* overall was heavily inspired by Cushing's performance:

  From [Luceno interview with SciFiNow](http://www.scifinow.co.uk/news/star-wars-7-exclusive-james-luceno-on-tarkin-eu-canon/)

  > **Q**: Did you find yourself revisiting earlier Cushing performances to capture his mannerisms?
  >
  > **JL**: Absolutely, yeah. I grew up watching... those were Hammer movies if I’m not mistaken, those great old horror movies that I remember him in. Everything from Revenge Of Frankenstein and Hound Of The Baskervilles – he was even in [an Amicus] Dr Who film, at one point! So all of my early filmgoing, he was a regular person who I saw on screen.
  >
  > I did try and make use of that in terms of helping flesh out his personality, his mannerisms, his general style.
- Luceno in general seems to be very detail oriented when it comes to continuity:

  > **Q**: You weave a lot of continuity into your stories. Is that easy or hard? Do you spend a lot of time on Wookieepedia or the Holocron?
  >
  > **Luceno**: When I first became involved with the franchise thirteen years ago, I made it a goal to catch up on everything that had been written up to that point and to stay current on every book that came out. Plus I have one of those brains that is capable of keeping a lot of stories in place. So the continuity references were already there. I just felt like I inhabited this big world where all these events have taken place. It’s the history of the Star Wars galaxy. And I enjoy emphasizing continuity. It’s not everybody’s cup of tea to find all those references in a book, but for me they make the world a bit more realistic.
  >
  > [(*Source*)](http://fangirlblog.com/interviews/james-luceno/)

Comment: You post a nice answer and then *delete* it before going into exile? Seriously. :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - IMHO it was not very useful as far as answering the question. I think OP agrees. I don't mind it being undeleted but personally don't think it's worth staying around.

Comment: Looks to me like one of those "not a complete answer, but probably the best we're ever going to get" answers. Note that I was the third vote to undelete (and a third non-mod had *flagged* for undeletion), so no mod abuse occurred! ;-) And of course you can delete it again if you *really* want.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'll let the OP decide. If he wants to flag it for deletion I'm fine. If not, let it stay.

Comment: I'm just happy I finally got a chance to upvote.  I don't see any reason to delete it.

Comment: While it's not a direct answer, this does heavily imply that the reference was intended based on the caricature of the author being detailed-oriented and very familiar with the nuances of Cushing's performances. Worth keeping around IMO, even if only to serve as a base for a thorough answer later if more information becomes known.